# find img tag inside a tag with regex

Tags: c#, regex, image, hyperlink

I have a HTML string and I want to find image links like `<a href="link1"><img src="link2"/></a>`

I try this regex pattern but it's not working: `"\<a\s.*\<img.*\<\/a\>"`

When I use that pattern it finds a string like `<a href="link1">some text1</a>some text2.<a href="link1"><img src="link2"/></a>` but I don't want first `<a href` part. I just want img tags inside a tag and I need help about it.

Comment: Why not use an HTML parser instead?

Comment: I would say use HTML parser (like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)) [instead of regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). But for this simple case maybe just use groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want only part of your overall regex you need to use groups or back references`( )`.

```
"\<a\s.*\(<img.*\/>)<\/a\>"
```

Then depending on the language you need to get the first group.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

**Update:** 
To match exactly  try:

```
 \<a[^<]*\<img.*\<\/a\>
```

instead of a `\s` I used `[^<]` which is any character except a `<`.

Comment: This will not work for me because I want not just something inside img tags. I want img tags inside a tag together. I will cover that string with a html code with some css and publish it to my service. I need exactly a string which is `<a href="link1"><img src="link2"/></a>`

Comment: added update that should match only the inner <a><img></a>. You may need to adjust to handle spaces or other differences.